# Py + SeleniumWebdriver - NoSuchElementException not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I can't understand why isn't this working? I know that there is no such element on this page, but `NoSuchElementException` isn't raised!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.kinopoisk.ru/')
try:
    driver.find_element_by_name('kp_query1')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('WTF')
print('Ok!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of more information about why you felt [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) does't rises would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer.

---

However, I took your code and when executed [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715) was properly caught and the `except{}` block was properly executed.

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.kinopoisk.ru/')
  try:
      driver.find_element_by_name('kp_query1')
  except NoSuchElementException:
      print('WTF')
  print('Ok!')
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  WTF
  Ok!
  ```

Comment: Funny thing - on my Ububtu laptop - it`s working, all ok! But on my windows computer - not working! thx)